# bitcoin адреса. формат

Tags: python, format, bitcoin, криптография, address

```
from bitcoinaddress import Wallet


wallet = Wallet()
print(wallet)
```

Вывод:

```
Private Key HEX: 03902e4f09664bc177fe4e090dcd9906b432b50f15fb6151984475c1c75c35b6
Private Key WIF: 5HqrbgkWPqBy6dvCE7FoUiMuiCfFPRdtRsyi6NuCM2np8qBZxq5
Private Key WIF compressed: KwLdv6T2jmhQbswnYrcL9KZHerTpVyjozp1JNjfP5QuD3GchCwCc 

Public Key: 04c5389a31ce6149c28ba20d14db8540b2319e5a65000a2919fbf7a6296e7840b53f883a9483fb7f2b43f3eacd857c904d1b70ecc168571b64d8f1ab82b57eea88 
Public Key compressed: 02c5389a31ce6149c28ba20d14db8540b2319e5a65000a2919fbf7a6296e7840b5

Public Address 1: 1Bu6YxH64nfvhdDsYNEP8PftoBMqgusdPS   
Public Address 1 compressed: 18i5PtPisxbGiGGEviW7HPcnfNPmcsscwH   
Public Address 3: 38dRrGx5YbrnRWuWcJv5i2XHjYUnHE2wvv  
Public Address bc1 P2WPKH: bc1q2jxe5azr6zmhk3258av7ul6cqtu4eu4mps8f4p    
Public Address bc1 P2WSH: bc1qdveuf0egtfdnd2fnsp0lzfukn2e58czf8323ky6xt8ydew4ecfcqv3ettx
```

Используя python, я хочу генерировать btc адреса, однако мне выводит целый суп из адресов. Я не понимаю: все эти ключи относятся к одному счёту, но записаны в разных форматах? Или здесь 3 различных счёта с одним приватным ключём, записаным в разных форматах?

Comment: Все эти биткоин адреса сделаны на одну приватную фразу (доступ к ним есть по одной приватной фразе), получать битки ты можешь на любой из них (публичный адрес)

Comment: Да, они записаны в разных форматах